# How to save user data in a python/pygame game

Tags: python, pygame, save, load

I don't mind if the save is readable or not, I don't plan on making this game big, just mainly for friends. I'm fairly new to python/pygame, and all of the tutorials don't really make sense to me. All I want is a way to save game progress, and when they return there progress is there. Anything helps!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make save / load game functions in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420311/how-to-make-save-load-game-functions-in-pygame)

Comment: I've got a complete example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45374532/6220679

Answer (score 2):

You need to save some representation of the game's current state. This can be any format you want -- if you have a game state object, you can serialize and save it using the `pickle` module, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420311/how-to-make-save-load-game-functions-in-pygame). If you have something simple that you could describe in a text file, e.g. something that reads like

```
score = 300
level = 10
lives = 2
```

then you could just save it in a text file when the user exits, and then load it when they start again.

Comment: So what would the code for that be, say I create a text file called user_data inside my game folder. Inside of the txt file do I write my variables? Or do I need to do it in python.

Comment: @Zane just do some googling about how to read/write files with python.

Comment: I figured out how to read and write but how do I implement it as variables, right now I have a variable called LevelOneWin, and for a test i'm setting it to true in my txt file. What would I do to use that in my code.

Comment: @Zane Combine your knowledge of reading/writing files with [the documentation on strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq) -- specifically string equality and converting to (and from) other datatypes.